# CanCan + Devise for the devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

Using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), I have a User model. I do not have a user controller.

To use CanCan I need to do (below) at the top of my controllers

```
# Authorization w Devise & CanCan
before_filter :authenticate_user! # Devise, signed in users only
load_and_authorize_resource # CanCan
```

Where do I add this so I can have permissions for the User model given I have no user controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add that code to any controller for which you need authentication, you don't need an `UsersController`

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

this line require a valid user signed in with devise, so if you try to access a controller with this before_filter without being logged you'll be redirected by devise to the `sign_in_path`

```
load_and_authorize_resource # CanCan
```

this other line will fill an instance variable to a default value (if not already set) and then check your privileges using the `Ability` class, so assuming you have an `ArticleController` it will do the following behind the scenes (actual code is based on the current action)

```
# for the show action
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless can(:read, @article)
```

The `can(:read, @article)` statement is the hearth of CanCan library, it will return a boolean value based on your ability class. Can read more on it [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

If your whole application requires authentication you can simply add the `before_filter :authenticate_user!` line to the `ApplicationController`

Comment: Right but where can I set that a user can modify there info but not a password using CanCan.

Comment: For that the default rules defined in `load_and_authorize_resource` are not good. The simplest way to do that is to use [attr_accessible or attr_protected macros of ActiveRecord class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) and update user attributes with mass assignment. Don't need CanCan for a task like that. For other usage of ability class read [my previous link](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

Comment: You can create custom abilities (e.g. `can? :edit, :password`) with CanCan and check against those as needed in your application.